# Sort array values and store into another array

Tags: arrays, c

I am aiming to sort an array and then store these values once sorted inside another array. However, my for-loop continues on infinitely long until I signal the console to stop the function.

For example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

//Sort the array from largest to smallest and store
//it inside another array

int main(int argc, char* argv[argc+1]){
    int arr[] = { 9, 6, 4, 6, 3, 2, 8, 1 };
    int result[] = {};
    for(int i = 0; i < malloc(sizeof(arr)); i++){
       result[i] = strtod(arr[i]);
       printf("%s",result);
    }
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: `i < malloc(sizeof(arr))` - What do you think this expression does?

Comment: ... and if your compiler is not emitting a warning about that, then turn up the warning level or get a better compiler.

Comment: Why are you using `strtod`? Why is `printf` expecting a string? Do you know what `result` is?

Comment: Why are you tryin to store values in a 0-length array?

Comment: `char* argv[argc+1]` is not something you'll want to do. Use `char** argv` or `char* argv[]`.

Comment: Your allocations are being thrown in the trash. This is a memory leak machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Incorrect Main Defination**

The declaration of the main function is incorrect.
There are two valid main declarations:

```
int main(void)
```

Or

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

where argc is the argument count, and argv is an array of character pointers.

**Invalid array declaration**

```
int result[] = {}
```

You declared an array of unspecified size, or 0 size.

The common C idiom to determine the size of an array is:

```
sizeof arr / sizeof arr[0]
```

Number of total bytes / number of bytes of a single element.

**Incorrect use of malloc**

```
malloc(sizeof(arr))
```

malloc is a library function that allows you to dynamically allocate memory from the heap. That is not what you want to do.

**Incorrect use of strtod**

```
strtod(arr[i])
```

strtod stands for string to double, why are you trying to convert integers stored in an array that are not strings to double?

**Incorrect format specifier**

```
printf("%s", result);
```

result is an integer array, not a string. Why are you specifying a %s for integers? Not that a %d would correct it.

You said you're trying to sort the array. Did you try thinking of an algorithm for it? Did you research anything? I'd advise you to start all over again and pick up a good C book. There are too many problem in this code, it's not salvageable.